# Call async method from sync callback in Python

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

The following python script uses read temperature from Ruuvi tag. In the synchronous Ruuvi callback we want to call a method that is async (send_message_to_output). The following code will on the second time it's called raise an exception

> RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

How can I get handle_data to work multiple times?

```
import asyncio
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
from ruuvitag_sensor.ruuvi import RuuviTagSensor

async def main():
    device_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()
    await device_client.connect()

    def handle_data(found_data):
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(device_client.send_message_to_output("some data", "ruuvi"))

    while True:
        RuuviTagSensor.get_datas(handle_data)
        time.sleep(5)

    await device_client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What about `create_task` for each of the `send_message_to_output` calls instead of `run_until_complete`.
Use the latter instead of the `asyncio.run` and pass the loop to the main as param?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I will answer with two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your exception it seems that the loop is closed for some reason.
I think it is due to the `run_until_complete` at the `handle_data` function that cause a reaction that closes the loop.

Therefor I would suggest to try the following:

```
import asyncio
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
from ruuvitag_sensor.ruuvi import RuuviTagSensor

async def main(main_loop):
    tasks = list()
    device_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()
    await device_client.connect()

    def handle_data(found_data):
        nonlocal main_loop
        nonlocal tasks
        tasks.append(main_loop.create_task(device_client.send_message_to_output("some data", "ruuvi")))

    while True:
        RuuviTagSensor.get_datas(handle_data)
        # We need to wait async in order to let the tasks run
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

    # This is just an insurance that all the tasks (messages to output) completed
    await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=5)
    await device_client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Creating and closing the loop here
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop)
    loop.close()
```

---

Alternative (*more complex*) solution can be using a function that read from a queue and call the `send_message_to_output` function:

```
import asyncio
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
from ruuvitag_sensor.ruuvi import RuuviTagSensor

async def main(main_loop):
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    stopping = asyncio.Event()

    device_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()
    await device_client.connect()

    async def send_msg():
        nonlocal q
        nonlocal stopping
        nonlocal device_client
        while not stopping.is_set():
            msg, sender = await q.get()
            if msg is None and sender is None:
                break
            await device_client.send_message_to_output(msg, sender)

    def handle_data(found_data):
        nonlocal q
        nonlocal stopping
        if stopping.is_set():
            return
        q.put_nowait(("some data", "ruuvi"))

    while True:
        RuuviTagSensor.get_datas(handle_data)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

    send_msg_task = main_loop.create_task(send_msg())

    await q.put((None, None))
    await stopping.set()
    await send_msg_task
    await device_client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop)
    loop.close()
```

The idea here was to separate the `handle_data` from the `send_msg`.
This way I manage to make the `send_msg` an async function that now does not need to create `loop` or a `Task`

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the task will start automatically after it has been created and appended to the list? We don't have to await the tasks? This regarding the first example.

Comment: I added tasks = [task for task in tasks if task._state != 'FINISHED'] after get_datas call to clean tasks from the list